# Plancherel for tempered distributions, and when does equality as tempered distributions imply equality as functions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

**Set-Up**

Let $f$ be a tempered distribution given by integration against a function (which we also call $f$). Suppose that there is a function $g \in L^2$ such that $\mathcal{F}f = g$. In other words, the tempered distribution $\mathcal{F}f$ is given by integration against an $L^2$ function.

**Question**

Do we have 
$$
\int |f|^2  = \int |g|^2 ? 
$$

**Observations**

- $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)$ is an $L^2$ function, so it suffices to prove $f(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)(x)$ as functions for a.e. $x$.
- $\int f \psi = \int \mathcal{F}^{-1}(g) \psi$ for all Schwartz functions $\psi$, so that $f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)$ as tempered distributions.
- If $f$ and $g$ are continuous bounded functions, then 
  $$
  f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f \ast \psi_{\epsilon} (x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} g \ast \psi_{\epsilon} (x) = g(x) \quad \text{for all $x$}, 
  $$
  where $\psi_{\epsilon}$ is a Schwartz approximation to the identity.

**Sub-Question** If two functions are equal as tempered distributions, under what conditions are they equal (or equal a.e.) as functions?

**Special Case**

This special case is connected to [Convolution theorem with distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679752/convolution-theorem-with-distributions)

- Take $f = u \ast \varphi$, where $\varphi \in S$ (Schwartz space) and $u \in S'$ (space of tempered distributions).
- With appropriate conditions on $u$, the tempered distribution $\mathcal{F}(u \ast \varphi)$ is integration against a function $g \in L^2$.
- Note $u \ast \varphi$ is the function defined by 
  $$
  (u \ast \varphi)(x) = \langle u, R \tau_x   \varphi \rangle,
  $$ 
  where $\tau_x \phi(y)=\phi(y-x)$ and $R\tau_x\phi(y) = \phi(x-y)$. In the particular case where $u$ is a function, 
  $$
  (u \ast \varphi)(x) = \int u(y) \phi(x-y) dx.
  $$
  Note also $u \ast \varphi$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function and a tempered distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, note that
\begin{align*}
\left<\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}L_{f}),h\right>&=\left<\mathcal{F}L_{f},\mathcal{F}^{-1}(h)\right>\\
&=\left<L_{f},\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}^{-1}h\right>\\
&=\left<L_{f},h\right>\\
&=\left<f,h\right>,
\end{align*}
where $h\in C_{0}^{\infty}({\bf{R}}^{n})$, so $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}L_{f}=f$ a.e., that is, $\mathcal{F}^{-1}g=f$ a.e. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a bijection in $L^{2}$, so $f\in L^{2}$ and that $\|f\|_{L^{2}}=\|\mathcal{F}(f)\|_{L^{2}}=\|g\|_{L^{2}}$ follows by the isometric property of $\mathcal{F}$, which is Parseval's formula.

For the second question, it must be the case that $f=g$ a.e. Actually a theorem says that if
\begin{align*}
\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}f(x)h(x)=\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}g(x)h(x)dx,~~~~h\in C_{0}^{\infty}({\bf{R}}^{n}),
\end{align*}
then $f=g$ a.e., where $C_{0}^{\infty}({\bf{R}}^{n})$ means all $C^{\infty}({\bf{R}}^{n})$ functions that having compactly supports and here $f,g\in L_{\text{loc}}^{1}({\bf{R}}^{n})$. The same result is true if we consider any open set $\Omega$ instead of ${\bf{R}}^{n}$.

Comment: Is your second assertion really true for arbitrary $f,g$? And do I presume correctly that $C_0^{\infty}$ means $C^{\infty}$ with compact support (rather than vanishing at infinity)?

Comment: $f,g\in L_{\text{loc}}^{1}({\bf{R}}^{n})$.